# How does Audio metadata works?

Tags: applications, bluetooth, audio, bluetooth-audio

I have an Android device on which I want to pair phone/laptop and play songs:

1. When I pair my phone and I play a song, the song's metadata is displayed on the Android device.
2. When I pair my laptop to the Android device and I play the same songs, the metadata is not displayed.

Why? Any explanation?

Comment: I forgot to write what type of device you pair with your Android in first case, I assume you have some Bluetooth headphone? In the second case you pair the phone with your computer. What OS runs on the computer? What Bluetooth profiles are supported by the computer (I would assume that a computer does not provide the BT headphone/audio profile)?

Comment: Additionally shown meta data are shown by the player app. Therefore you should edit your question and add the name and Play Store link of audio player app you use.